# How to consider variation while switching theme?

Tags: java, android, dynamic, themes

I'm Working on an android app that has a requirement to switch theme based on the `themeCode` given from server. I'm using `sharePref` to save the theme code and applying it with `setTheme(R.style.themeName);`. Its working fine till the basic theme attributes like

```
colorPrimary
colorPrimaryDark
colorAccent
windowActionBar
windowNoTitle
```

For this I has created different styles in `styles.xml`. But I have a limitation that some fields say `EditText` has variation as EditText

- person name
- email
- phone
- password etc.

And similarly `TextView` has variation as TextView

- Heading
- Single Line
- Mutiline
- Link etc.

Before multi-theme requirement I had created separate themes for all as

- Apptheme.Edittext.email
- Apptheme.Edittext.Password
- Apptheme.Edittext.PersonName etc.
  And was applying to specific view in xml like

  ```
   style="@style/AppTheme.EditText.PersonName"
  ```

Now I have viewed many tutorials/posts but did not find solution to the variations in attribute. Please help to apply these variation, I'll be thankful for this.

Regards:
Inzimam Tariq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is create custom attributes for your view types (e.g. `TextView.Person`, `TextView.Date`...), in your xml you can reference the attributes and then define the attributes in different themes. For instance, you style.xml could be

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" >
        <item name="TextView.Date">@style/DateTextViewDefault</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DateTextViewDefault">
        <item name="android:textColor">#ff333333</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">monospace</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Theme A -->
    <style name="AppTheme.A">
        <item name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
        <item name="TextView.Person">@style/PersonTextViewA</item>
    </style>

    <style name="PersonTextViewA">
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">serif</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#ff999999</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Theme B -->
    <style name="AppTheme.B">
        <item name="colorPrimary">#888888</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#555555</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#000000</item>
        <item name="TextView.Person">@style/PersonTextViewB</item>
        <item name="TextView.Date">@style/DateTextViewB</item>
    </style>

    <style name="PersonTextViewB">
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">monospace</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#ff55aa</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DateTextViewB">
        <item name="android:textColor">#ff0000BB</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif</item>
    </style>

    <attr name="TextView.Person" format="reference" />
    <attr name="TextView.Date" format="reference" />

</resources>
```

then your activity xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        style="?attr/TextView.Person"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="John Doe" />

    <TextView
        style="?attr/TextView.Date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="31/12/1999" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonA"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="THEME A" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="THEME B" />

</LinearLayout>
```

notice that the styles of the `TextView` are

```
style="?attr/TextView.Person"
```

and

```
style="?attr/TextView.Date"
```

`AppTheme.A` and `AppTheme.B` have 2 different resolutions for those attributes

In this example the attributes are entire styles for your views but you could easily have one style per view type (`TextView.person`) and then define generic attributes for single items of that style, e.g.

```
<attr name="TextView.Person.TextColor" format="color" />
```

and only change that single attribute in your themes.

Then in your `Activity` you just need to set the theme in `onCreate` with `setTheme(int)`, the value could be in this case either `R.style.AppTheme_A` or `R.style.AppTheme_B`.

With this method you can add as many styles as you want without touching the layouts. Also, you can always define some default styles in your base theme and then only override that value in some of the custom themes, while others use the default one as for `TextView.Date` in the sample above.

If you want to give it a quick try, here's the code of the `Activity` I used to test `style.xml` and `activity_main.xml` above

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val prefs by lazy { getSharedPreferences("SharedPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE) }

    private var customTheme: Int
        get() = prefs.getInt("theme", R.style.AppTheme_A)
        set(value) = prefs.edit()
                .putInt("theme", value)
                .apply()
                .also { recreate() }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setTheme(customTheme)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        buttonA.setOnClickListener { customTheme = R.style.AppTheme_A }
        buttonB.setOnClickListener { customTheme = R.style.AppTheme_B }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the above code in Kotline? It does not seems like Java Class

Comment: Correct, that's Kotlin

Comment: @InzimamTariqIT please notice that the solution is not related to Kotlin at all, that's just a quick test

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion changing app theme at runtime, will **definitely need to reload activity**; this in most cases will create issues at some point (if project is extended to a mid scale, having a **user control** like toggle or a switch and if user **taps switch repeatedly** app may easily crash)

---

I would suggest to use **custom control classes** (Textviews, Buttons..etc); wherein this properties are differentiated with current theme value from sharedPref. 
This approach has a con; it will require to change all views manually of current screen and those in already rendered in memory(if any), rest all it will be much smoother transition in compare to our conventional approach

### EDIT: Example for CustomTextView ##

This is an example for customtextview class

```
public class CustomTextView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView {
private static final String TAG = "TextView";
private Typeface tf = null;
private SharedPreferenceUtils preferenceUtils = SharedPreferenceUtils.getInstance();

/**
 * @param context:This is an abstract class whose implementation is provided by Android Operating System.
 * @param attrs:A      collection of attributes, as found associated with a tag in an XML document.
 * @param defStyle:
 */
public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    if (preferenceUtils.getBooleanValue(PrefsKeyValue.bTheme)) {
        this.setTextColor(ResourceUtils.getColor(R.color.lightThemeTextColor));
    } else {
        this.setTextColor(ResourceUtils.getColor(R.color.colorWhite));
    }

    try {
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                R.styleable.CustomEditText, defStyle, 0);

        String str = a.getString(R.styleable.CustomTextView_FontEnum);
        int original = a.getInt(R.styleable.CustomEditText_FontEnum, 0);
        CustomEnum.CustomFontType customEnumValue = CustomEnum.CustomFontType.fromId(a.getInt(R.styleable.CustomEditText_FontEnum, 0));
        a.recycle();
        switch (customEnumValue) {
            case BOLD:
                setTypeface(HelveticaNeueBold.getInstance(context).getTypeFace());
                break;

            case LIGHT:
                setTypeface(HelveticaNeueMedium.getInstance(context).getTypeFace());
                break;

            case REGULAR:
                setTypeface(HelveticaNeue.getInstance(context).getTypeFace());
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}


public boolean setCustomFont(Context ctx, String asset) {

    try {
        tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(), asset);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LogUtils.LogE(TAG, "Could not get typeface: " + e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }

    setTypeface(tf);
    return true;
}}
```

Herein I have changed textcolor in accordance to theme value from sharedPref

```
 if (preferenceUtils.getBooleanValue(PrefsKeyValue.bTheme)) {
        this.setTextColor(ResourceUtils.getColor(R.color.lightThemeTextColor));
    } else {
        this.setTextColor(ResourceUtils.getColor(R.color.colorWhite));
    }
```

Then use this class as textview tag in xml file.

```
    <com.mypkg.customview.CustomTextView
    style="@style/signup_textViewStyle"
    android:text="@string/activity_login_password" />
```

I believe, you can handle property variation with theme for controls in same manner.

Comment: In my app user will not change the theme,  it will be set by the owner of the app at server. So before instantiating any view I can the theme.

Comment: And setting theme is not problem, the problem is to handle the variations. Can you add a short example?

Comment: how to pass second param to constructor? I mean AttributeSet attrs

Comment: No need to call that constructor pro grammatically.
just add properties to if else above, and xml, findview in accordance, and you will be good to go.

Comment: This would be a long process as the attribute & styles variations increase. A way shorter would be nice else I would try this way. Anyway +1 & thanks for your effort.

Comment: 1 thing more how can I get to know about TextView (if its a link TextView/Multiline/SingleLine OR Heading?)